# My type predicate function does not work as I would expect. Need help understanding why

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Consider the following type predicate function to check if an object contains a specific key:

```js
export function objectHasKey<T extends object>(
  obj: T,
  key: PropertyKey,
  includeKeysFromPrototype: boolean = false,
): key is keyof T {
  return includeKeysFromPrototype ? key in obj : Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key);
}
```

Now, consider the following dummy code to illustrate my confusion:

```js
let entry: unknown = {
  someProperty: '123'
}

// (1) EXPECTED -> TS2339: Property 'someProperty' does not exist on type 'unknown'
console.log(entry.someProperty)

if (typeof entry === 'object' && objectHasKey(entry, 'someProperty')) {
  // (2) UNEXPECTED -> TS2339: Property 'someProperty' does not exist on type 'object'
  console.log(entry.someProperty)
}
```

I do not understand why TypeScript raises an error at (2), even though I have explicitly checked that `someProperty` is a key of `entry` using my type predicate function.

Comment: Your type predicate narrows the `key` input to `keyof T` (which, since `T` is just `object` or something like it, becomes `never`), and you're never reusing that key anyway  Type predicates act on the references passed in.  You really can't narrow a primitive like that.  Conceptually you want instead to narrow the `obj` input to `T & Record<K, any>` (where `K` is the generic type of the `key` input) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAPyBN).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: The playground example really helped me understand what you explained to me, and addresses the issue at hand perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function

```
declare function objectHasKey<T extends object>(
  obj: T, key: PropertyKey, includeKeysFromPrototype: boolean
): key is keyof T
```

returns the [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) `key is keyof T`, which means that when you call `objectHasKey(obj, key)` and it returns `true`, the apparent type of the `key` input will be narrowed to `keyof T` (equivalent to `keyof typeof obj`).  The apparent type of the `obj` input will not be changed at all.  So if `obj` is of type `object` and `key` is a string literal like `"prop"`, then a `true` result means that sting literal `"prop"` will be narrowed from `"prop"` to `keyof object` which is [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  This is not your intent.  Even if it were your intent, type predicates only serve to narrow the actual input.  If that input is a string literal like `"prop"`, any resulting change will be inaccessible because you never reuse a string literal again.  In order for that to work you'd need to use a *variable* or a *property* like `const k = "prop"` and then `objectHasKey(obj, k)`.

But anyway, this isn't your intent.  Your code assumes that after you call `objecthasKey(obj, key)` and it returns `true`, the apparent type of *the `obj` input* will change so that it is known to have `key` as a key.  That means you need to change your type predicate to be of the form `obj is` instead of `key is`.  Here's one way to do that (and there are multiple ways):

```
declare function objectHasKey<K extends PropertyKey>(
  obj: object,
  key: K,
  includeKeysFromPrototype: boolean = false,
): obj is Record<K, any>;
```

This function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` of `key`.  A `true` result narrows `obj` from `object` to `Record<K, any>` (using the [`Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)).  Now your code works as desired:

```
if (entry && typeof entry === 'object' && objectHasKey(entry, 'someProperty')) {
  console.log(entry.someProperty) // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXxwCMArcDACSgGcBpEATwA0AeAFXhAA8MRVgqCJMgD4AFACh4g4gC54rADTwA1gzkAFGDgAOIGBnp16SrOgjJQRqgDEtAW004MT+rrmEcOCCCipxASjlVengsAWCcRHlxcS5tHH0kNExcfCJSTEpaBmYaDm5efnhHXX1DBjFJaTl0sgUq4LkaeqlTSAsQK1scBy1nAzd4Dy8ffABeJCgIKhB6wOlQgQAlcATgXKVfemF4AG8quAxkGHw280sGG3tHftcEAH4VBlC0kng5AHkhTAA6bT6XLofgALagfADuqBKegMPzAUwgonSSmC-gA3OIAL4xbwYDioDAwehyNDKVA4SHwCb7KRUHogaFlOQAcgAjAAmADMzKxMXEWCiol4hJCADJRfABiBIviRVSxhNmbVMMz4OLpGQskYhQSiUpmXS7AytKUDMz-P49lUwHg6d4fhAcABzHUin6G406GH0S0Ael9BGUUHovKAA)

Comment: Cannot thank you enough for the extensive answer. Very well explained.